# Is it possible to show navbar for a web resource in Dynamics CRM?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dynamics-crm

I'm wondering if it's possible to show the navbar for Dynamics CRM when you're loading a web resource directly with url(`/WebResources/WebResource?data=exampleData`). I have tried with `/WebResources/WebResource?data=exampleData&web=true` but no luck.

I have been able to show the navbar for my web resource when adding it to the navigation menu and loading it with this url(`/main.aspx?page=Area&area=NewSubArea&web=true`). But I haven't been able to pass data in the url with this solution.

Comment: A web resource does not have a nav bar. Are you hinting at the application ribbon?

Comment: This is not possible. What's the idea behind this?

Comment: @Nick I'm developing a screen pop feature in Dynamics which pops the account from the number that's calling. If the number exists on more than one account I want to present these accounts on a page were the user can choose which one to open. 

Just want the page to look more like "Dynamics", guess I will have to develop my own version of it.

Comment: @AlexanderBacklund you can clone/copy the CRM CSS from browser developer toolbar & use it in your HTML as web resources to match look & feel.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `navBar` option is available only for [Xrm.Navigation.openForm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/clientapi/reference/xrm-navigation/openform) under `entityFormOptions`, where you can give the values `on/off/entity`

For [Xrm.Navigation.openWebResource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/clientapi/reference/xrm-navigation/openwebresource) that option is not there, so only way to achieve is copying the CRM CSS classes from browser developer toolbar & use it in your HTML to match the look & feel. This is unsupported as it may break in future.

But you can inspire the CSS file content & mimic in custom CSS as web resources.